# I don't know how to do a buffer in this code

Tags: python, mysql, buffer

This code is to do querys and they give me this error

mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found

I have searched for this error and found that I have to do a buffer but I have no idea how to put a buffer here. How can i buffer this code? Can someone help me?

This is the `code`:

```
 import mysql.connector
    from mysql.connector import Error
    class DataBase:
        def __init__(self):
            self.connection = mysql.connector.connect(
                host = '',
                user="",
                password='',
                db=''
            )
            self.cursor= self.connection.cursor()
            #self = self.cursor(buffered=True)
            print ("Ha funcionat")
           #print ("1 Buscar /2 Update / 3 Tancar Conexio")
           #dia=input("Posa el que vols fer")
        def select_user(self):
            sql = " SELECT * FROM Diccionari"
            try:
                self.cursor.execute(sql)
                user = self.cursor.fetchone()
                print(user)
            except Exception as e:
                raise
        def select_llenguatje(self):
            Lenguaje = str(input("Seleccione el lenguaje : "))
            llenguatje = "SELECT * FROM Diccionari WHERE Lenguaje = '"+Lenguaje+"'"
            try:
                self.cursor.execute(llenguatje)
                user = self.cursor.fetchone()
                print(user)
            except Exception as a:
                raise
        def update_user(self):
            Lenguaje1 = input("Posa el llenguatje: ")
            Comandos = input("Posa el Comandos: ")
            Descripcion = input("Posa el Descripcion: ")
            Notas = input("Posa el Notas: ")
            #id = input("Posa la id: ")
            update = ("INSERT INTO Diccionari SET Lenguaje= '"+Lenguaje1+"', Comandos= '"+Comandos+"', Descripcion= '"+Descripcion+"', Notas='"+Notas+"';")
            #val =("C++, if,pot ser,no")
            #val = (Lenguaje1, Comandos, Descripcion, Notas, id )  
            #update = "INSERT INTO Diccionari (Lenguaje,Comandos,Descripcion,Notas, ID) VALUES ('"+Lenguaje1+"','"+Comandos+"','"+Descripcion+"','"+Notas+"','"+id+"');" 
            try:
                self.cursor.execute(update)
                users = self.cursor(buffered=True)
                #users = self.cursor.fetchone()
                print(users)
            except Exception as u:
                raise
        def close(self):
            self.connection.close()
            print ("Se ha cerrado la conexion")
    database = DataBase()
    database.select_user()
    Lenguaje = input("Seleccione el lenguaje : ")
    database.select_llenguatje()
    database.update_user()
    database.close()
```

Comment: Could you point us to where it says "You have to use a buffer"?

Comment: If you serch the error you can look that old the persons sey de same. But if you know somthing diferent you can sey to me